# Trigger a window.alert with the if and return true

Tags: javascript, html, triggers

Now, I'm a total noob when it comes to Javascript so this is probably really easy but; 
I grabbed this code that I found elsewhere here on Stack Overflow which is supposed to detect if the device loading in the webpage is a mobile device. What I want to do is simply being able to take the values from it and trigger a window.alert message telling them to go into landscape mode.

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
          function detectmob() {
      if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
      ){
      return true;
      }
      else {
      return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="detectmob()">
```

Comment: Get rid of the two `return` statements and replace them with appropriate `alert()` statements. And, consider not doing this at all and using CSS Media Queries to create a responsive web design, since `navigator.userAgent` is not reliable.

Comment: Please don't. Nothing (almost) is not more annoying than a web page knowing better than me how I should hold my phone ...

Comment: Also (FYI), you can remove `language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"` from the code. That was necessary in the last version of HTML, but hasn't been needed in over 5 years.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the quick help! This was just a lot easier thinking back, I'll have to do some serious practice in JS eventually. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `return` statements here, you don't need them. Simply trigger the `alert` if the if condition is true.

```js
function detectmob() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
    navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
  ) {
    alert("Please put your phone into landscape mode.");
  } else {
    console.log("Desktop user.");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="detectmob()">
```